# Decide if radical expression equals a given rational number

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, radicals, rationality-testing

Given a radical expression an a rational number. Is there an algorithm to decide if the expression equals the number?

**Example**:

$(\sqrt{\sqrt[5]{74} - \sqrt[14]{78}})^{356}+\sqrt[6]{63} \overset{?}= 3$

Comment: If anybody's interested, this expression is about $3.000013589...$. See [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%2874%5E%281%2F5%29-78%5E%281%2F14%29%29%5E%28356%2F2%29%2B63%5E%281%2F6%29) for more digits.

Comment: See [almost integer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_integer).

Answer (score 0):

An expression that involves the operations addition, multiplication, root extraction (and NOT DIVISION)  with natural numbers will yield an algebraic integer. You claim that number is a rational number so it has to be an integer.  So if the number is *approximately* 3 then it will be exactly 3.

You have to  find the approximate value with control on errors using calculators, or numerical methods.